# Hibernate one to many and many to one relationship concept

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to learn Hibernate and just got a bit confused.

I have 2 classes Company and Employee. Company has a set of Employee.

So inside Company i have defined something like

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID")
private Set<Employee> employees;
```

1. Now do i need to define something like

   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID")
   private Company company;

inside Employee class as well and also how will it make the difference.

2. What will be the difference if i don't define ManyToOne mapping ?

Answer (score 0):

See https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/hibernate-manytoone-unidirectional-tutorial/

It all depends on whether you want a uni-directional one to many or a bi-directional one to many

Comment: Thanks for link Michael.